# Equality of equivalence classes for congruence modulo 7

Tags: elementary-number-theory, equivalence-relations, congruences

> Let R be the relation of congruence modulo 7. Which of the following equivalence classes are equal?
>   [35], [3], [−7], [12], [0], [−2], [17]

I got 3)    [35] = [-7] = [0], [3] = [17], [12] = [-2]
Is this right?

Comment: Yes.$\,\!\!\, $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is correct.  Two elements generate the same equivalence class if and only if their difference is a multiple of seven.

Comment: Let A = {a, b, c, d} and R be equivalence relation on the set A such that
 R = {(a, a), (b, b), (b, d), (c, c), (d, b), (d, d)}.  Find the distinct equivalence classes of R.

1)  {a}, {b}, {c}, {d}
 
2)  {a,b}, {b,c}, {c,d}
 
3)  {a,b, c, d}
 
4) {a}, {b,d}, {c}
please help me with this also.

Comment: Hi @rohit.  Please ask a new question.

Comment: I can't ask it says. not able to ask. please answer here